# ISNULL() OR Is NULL in UPDATE statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, update, null

I have to run an `UPDATE` statement on live online database with 500k records. I want to know which statement will run faster:

```
Update Table set REC_ID = isnull(REC_ID,'')

Update Table set REC_ID = '' where REC_ID is null
```

i am using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: If you've got SSMS: enter one update after the other and click the "Display Estimated Execution Plan" (Ctrl + L). This will compare the updates and you can get an indication of which one it *thinks* will be quicker.

Comment: Yes I checked the executive plan but after that I was Confafed then I was asking for the question.
thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those queries won't do the same thing.

```
Update Table set REC_ID = isnull(REC_ID,'')
```

This one will update each record and if `REC_ID` is `NULL` it will set it to `''`.

```
Update Table set REC_ID = '' where REC_ID is NULL
```

This one will only update records containing a null value in `REC_ID`, and set it to `''`.
While both of them will end up giving the same result, the second one will be executed on less records (except if every `REC_ID` is `NULL`), it should be faster.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference in above two cases is the first statement don't have a `where` clause so all the rows in the table will be updated irrespective of the fact that REC_ID is `NULL` or not. While in second case only those rows will be updated where `REC_ID is null`.

Performance would have been impacted when you had condition like:

```
Update Table set REC_ID = '' where isnull(REC_ID,'') =''
```

because in the above case the predicate is no longer a `search argument`. This means the SQL server cannot efficiently use an index on `REC_ID` column.

Comment: Your way is right, but I do not need this condition right now.
Thanks for your answer;

Answer (score -1):

I think you have a misunderstanding here. Those two statements do not do the same thing.

Run those commands in a sample dataset and you will see that they do not do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

In theory, the "winner" should (assuming there are no indexes):

```
Update Table set REC_ID = '' where REC_ID is null
```

There's a "IS_NULL" bitmap stored value that *should* quickly fetch the rows where REC_ID is NULL. SQL Server automatically saves a TRUE (1) value for each null column, and a FALSE (0) for each one that is not null. The other query presented has to evaluate *after* applying an ISNULL() function.

Answer (score -2):

The `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE` statement could be used to speed the search for matching rows when the field in question is part of an index. In this example, if *REC_ID* is indexed and the [selectivity](https://web.archive.org/web/20160223011836/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/bartd/archive/2011/01/25/query_5f00_tuning_5f00_key_5f00_terms.aspx) of the field is good, the `WHERE` clause will help, but if it's poor, a table scan will likely be required anyway and both statements will last almost the same.