# Update one table's row from the results of multiple rows of another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've seen posts on how to update multiple rows (specifically using case?), but my question is the inverse.

I have a table of `phone_numbers`

| Person_ID | Phone_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 102-345-6789 |
| 1 | 102-445-6789 |
| 2 | 102-545-6789 |

And a table of `contacts`:

| peopleid | Phone_number_1 | Phone_number_2 | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | Joe |
| 2 |  |  | Bob |

I'd like to get the `phone_numbers` into the one row of the `contacts` table.

And all I have is a hot mess of attempts, none of which have worked, mostly because I'm doing joins? that are not [explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314134/the-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound)? so the multi-part identifiers don't work.

I wanted to make sure I was getting [each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28506747/sql-loop-through-each-row-in-a-table) (and not just the first row of what the join decides), so I did this:

```
DECLARE @id int
SELECT @id = min(e1.Person_ID)
FROM out_1E e1
WHILE @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  -- other stuff below


  select @id = min( Person_ID )
  from out_1E
  where Person_ID > @id
END
```

And then my attempt at the update statement inside, where I want it to [update the first column](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/isnull-or-is-null-in-update-statement) if null, and if not, the second column (I only care about the first two).

```
DECLARE @phone NVARCHAR
  SELECT @phone = contacts.Phone_number_1 -- THIS DOESN'T WORK
  IF @phone IS NULL

UPDATE contacts
SET [Phone_number_1] = isnull([Phone_number_1], e1.Phone_number)
FROM out_1E e1
WHERE contacts.peopleid = e1.Person_ID
```

In total:

```
DECLARE @id int
SELECT @id = min(e1.Person_ID)
FROM out_1E e1
WHILE @id IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  DECLARE @phone NVARCHAR
  SELECT @phone = contacts.Phone_number_1
  IF @phone IS NULL

  
   UPDATE contacts
SET [Phone_number_1] = isnull( [Phone_number_1], e1.Phone_Number)
FROM out_1E e1
WHERE contacts.peopleid = e1.Person_ID


  select @id = min( Person_ID )
  from out_1E
  where Person_ID > @id
END
```

These are not the column names, so if there are typos there, it's only on this post.

How would I go about correcting this so I iterate through each row of the `phone_numbers` table to populate the `contacts` table with phone numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an elegant solution, but I just split it up and added a WHERE clause on the second iteration.

```
UPDATE contacts
SET [Home Phone] = ISNULL([Home Phone], e1.Phone_Number)
FROM out_1E e1
WHERE contacts.peopleid = e1.Person_ID
AND [Person_Phone_or_email_Type] = 'HOME'

UPDATE contacts
SET [Home Phone 2] = ISNULL([Home Phone 2], e1.Phone_Number)
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN out_1E e1
ON contacts.peopleid = e1.Person_ID
WHERE [Home Phone] <> e1.Phone_Number
AND Person_Phone_or_email_Type = 'HOME'
```

I'm sure there's a better way of doing this, to be more inclusive, but this does appear to work.

Comment: There are columns in your answer that aren’t reflected in the schema you posted. Perhaps more accurate details would get you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your exact scenario, I usually just implement some kind of PIVOT logic in my code. Link to MSDN documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

To set up your tables as you have shown them, I've ran this code -

```
CREATE TABLE #phone_numbers
(
    id INT
  , phone_number VARCHAR(12)
);

CREATE TABLE #contacts
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  , phone_number_1 VARCHAR(12)
  , phone_number_2 VARCHAR(12)
  , name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO #contacts
VALUES
('', '', 'Joe')
, ('', '', 'Bob')
, ('', '', 'Steve');

INSERT INTO #phone_numbers
VALUES
(1, '102-345-6789')
, (1, '102-445-6789')
, (2, '102-545-6789')
, (2, '102-645-6789')
, (3, '102-845-6789');
```

Simply running a SELECT on those tables give me this -

```
id          phone_number
----------- ------------
1           102-345-6789
1           102-445-6789
2           102-545-6789
2           102-645-6789
3           102-845-6789

id          phone_number_1 phone_number_2 name
----------- -------------- -------------- ----------
1                                         Joe
2                                         Bob
3                                         Steve
```

Since your phone_number table doesn't really contain an order of phone numbers, I've just had it assume that there will be a maximum of two phone numbers in the phone_number table, and if there are more, those will just be ignored.

Running my select with my pivot below -

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.phone_number_1
     , c.phone_number_2
     , c.name
     , pn_display.[1]
     , pn_display.[2]
FROM #contacts AS c
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT pn_pvt.[1]
         , pn_pvt.[2]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pn.phone_number
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pn.id ORDER BY pn.id) AS rn
        FROM #phone_numbers AS pn
        WHERE c.id = pn.id
    ) AS pn_order
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(phone_number)
        FOR rn IN ([1], [2])
    ) pn_pvt
) AS pn_display;
```

Yields this table -

```
id          phone_number_1 phone_number_2 name       1            2
----------- -------------- -------------- ---------- ------------ ------------
1                                         Joe        102-345-6789 102-445-6789
2                                         Bob        102-545-6789 102-645-6789
3                                         Steve      102-845-6789
```

According to your specific request -

> And then my attempt at the update statement inside, where I want it to update the first column if null, and if not, the second column (I only care about the first two).

The update statement would look like this -

```
UPDATE c
SET c.phone_number_1 = IIF(ISNULL(c.phone_number_1, '') = '', [1], c.phone_number_1)
  , c.phone_number_2 = IIF(ISNULL(c.phone_number_1, '') != '', [2], c.phone_number_2)
FROM #contacts AS c
    CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT [1]
         , [2]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT pn.phone_number
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY pn.id ORDER BY pn.id) AS rn
        FROM #phone_numbers AS pn
        WHERE c.id = pn.id
    ) AS pn_order
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(phone_number)
        FOR rn IN ([1], [2])
    ) pn_pvt
) AS pn_display
WHERE (
          ISNULL(c.phone_number_1, '') = ''
          AND ISNULL([1], '') != ''
      )
      OR
      (
          ISNULL(c.phone_number_2, '') = ''
          AND ISNULL([2], '') != ''
      );
```

This statement would select only records where 1 or both of the 2 phone_number columns in the contacts table were null or empty yet 1 or 2 records in the phone_numbers table were available for that contact. If the phone_number_1 field were empty, it would populate only that field. If it wasn't empty, but the phone_number_2 field was, it would fill in the second number if there were a second entry for that specific id in the phone_numbers table. That ensures that even if there are no records to update, rows are not updated with existing data. Depending on the size of the table that could be a nasty performance hit.

Design choices aside, that's how you would get the following over 2 executions (The first for phone number 1, the second for phone number 2). If you executed the update three times, the first would update 3 rows, the second would update 2, and the third would update 0.

```
SELECT c.id
     , c.phone_number_1
     , c.phone_number_2
     , c.name
FROM #contacts AS c;

id          phone_number_1 phone_number_2 name
----------- -------------- -------------- ----------
1           102-345-6789   102-445-6789   Joe
2           102-545-6789   102-645-6789   Bob
3           102-845-6789                  Steve
```